# How to create LazyList Scala using LazyList.iterate?

Tags: scala, lazylist

My task:

1. Implement a function to calculate the [Look-and-say](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence) sequence.

This is done and the tests pass successfully:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.LazyList
import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object CountAndSay extends App {
  def nextLine(currentLine: List[BigInt]): List[BigInt] = {
    ...

  println(nextLine(List(1, 2, 1, 1)) == List(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1))
  println(nextLine(List(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1)) == List(3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1))
  println(nextLine(List(3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1)) == List(1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1))
}
```

2. Implement a lazy list that generates the given sequence.

```
val funSeq: LazyList[List[Int]] = ...
println(funSeq(5) === List(3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1))
```

To create a LazyList with nested lists, I want to use LazyList.iterate.
[LazyList.iterate description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpsXR.png)
But I get a Cannot resolve overloaded method 'iterate' error:

```
val funSeq: LazyList[List[BigInt]] = LazyList.iterate(List(1), nextLine(List(1)))
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `nextLine(List(1)` is not a function, you want to pass `nextLine` alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you do not use LazyList syntax correctly. You need to use it as follow:

```
LazyList.iterate(List(BigInt(1)))(nextLine).take(4).force
```

First parameter of iterate is start element that will passed in the function - second parameter of iterate. The *take* need to do several iterations and *force* need to evaluate result.